# Making a upper bound for the integral of integrable functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am proving something about uniform integrable families of functions and I need to prove something that seems easy but I stucked, it says:

Let be $(X,S,\mu)$ a measurable space, $g$ integrable and $\epsilon>0$ so exists $\delta>0$ s.t. If $E\in S$ with $\mu(E)<\delta$ then $\int_{E}|g|d\mu<\epsilon.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to prove that the measure induced by $|g|$ is absolutely continuous.

Given $\epsilon >0$, there is some simple function $\phi = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \chi_{A_i}$ such that $0\leq \phi\leq g$ and $\int \phi \geq \int g - \frac{\epsilon}2$

Note that 
$$\begin{align}
\int_{E} g &= \int_E (g-\phi) + \int_E\phi\\
&\leq \int (g-\phi) + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \mu(E\cap A_i)\\
&\leq \frac{\epsilon}2 + n\cdot \max  a_i \cdot \mu(E)
\end{align}$$

Therefore $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2n\max a_i}$ fits the bill.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am attempting to make bounds for a family of integrales where the domain of integrations is variable.

Comment: Good luck in your endeavors